# Firebase Realtime No properties to serialize found on class java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am currently using firebase recycler adapter and running into this error

> "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to
>   serialize found on class java.lang.CharSequence".

I am currently using a char sequence to retreive text from a button.

```
//Class for storing creating litter sightings
public class Item implements Serializable
{
    //class variables
    public CharSequence user;
    public String brief;

    //constructor
    public Item(CharSequence user, String brief)
    {
        this.user=user;
        this.brief=brief;
    }
    public Item()
    {

    }

    //getters
    public String getBrief() {
        return brief;
    }
    public void setBrief(String myBrief) {
       this.brief = myBrief;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: Please, explain your question enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have to must use Percable because

**Serializable**

Serializable is a standard Java interface. You can just implement Serializable interface and add override methods. The problem with this approach is that reflection is used and it is a slow process. This method creates a lot of temporary objects and causes quite a bit of garbage collection. However, Serializable interface is easier to implement.

**Parcelable**

Parcelable process is much faster than Serializable. One of the reasons for this is that we are being explicit about the serialization process instead of using reflection to infer it. It also stands to reason that the code has been heavily optimized for this purpose.

Look at the example below (Parcelable):

```
// MyObjects Parcelable class

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MyObjects implements Parcelable {

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> address;

    public MyObjects(String name, int age, ArrayList<String> address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public MyObjects(Parcel source) {
        age = source.readInt();
        name = source.readString();
        address = source.createStringArrayList();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(age);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeStringList(address);
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAddress() {
        if (!(address == null))
            return address;
        else
            return new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public static final Creator<MyObjects> CREATOR = new Creator<MyObjects>() {
        @Override
        public MyObjects[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyObjects[size];
        }

        @Override
        public MyObjects createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MyObjects(source);
        }
    };
}

// MyObjects instance
MyObjects mObjects = new MyObjects("name", "age", "Address array here");

// Passing MyOjects instance
Intent mIntent = new Intent(FromActivity.this, ToActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("UniqueKey", mObjects);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

**Conclusion**

Parcelable is faster than Serializable interface
Parcelable interface takes more time to implement compared to Serializable interface Serializable interface is easier to implement Serializable interface creates a lot of temporary objects and causes quite a bit of garbage collection
Parcelable array can be passed via Intent in android.